# SSDT Upgrade data when upgrading schema

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-data-tools

I have the following *example* scenario and I am looking for a way how to do a proper upgrade in a **Sql Server Database Project**.

I have 4 tables:

- CarColors

  - Id
  - ColorCode
- Cars

  - Id
  - CarColor_Id
- Trucks

  - Id
  - TruckColor_Id
- TruckColors

  - Id
  - ColorCode

`TruckColors` and `CarColors` are identical so I want to refactor this.

Desired changes:

- Rename `CarColors` to `ColorCodes`
- Rename `Cars.CarColor_Id` to `Cars.ColorCode_Id`
- Create `Trucks.ColorCode_Id` foreign key to `ColorCodes`
- **Fill 'Trucks.ColorCode_Id' based on the information of `Trucks.TruckColor_Id`**
- Remove `Trucks.TruckColor_Id` column
- Remove `TruckColors` table

I can only do a `PostDeploy` or a `PreDeploy` but that's either:

- To early because before migrating `Trucks.ColorCode_Id` does not exist.
- To late because `Trucks.TruckColor_Id` is already removed

So in the middle of the upgrade, I want to run this particular script:

```
UPDATE truck
SET truck.ColorCode_Id = newcolor.Id 
FROM Trucks truck 
INNER JOIN TruckColors truckcolor ON truck.TruckColor_Id = truckcolor.Id
INNER JOIN ColorCodes newcolor ON truckcolor.ColorCode = newcolor.ColorCode
```

Data is already in production so no dataloss should occur.
How can I achieve this with **Sql Server Database Projects**?

Comment: Which of these steps are you stuck on?   I don't understand what your exact question is.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use both the pre-deploy and post-deploy to complete the change for you:

In the pre-deploy save the data you need into a temp table (I would use an actual table call it migration_blah etc) this table should be in the project but you create it in your pre-deploy script.

The table migrations happen and then in your post deploy script you update your tables with the data from the temp intermediate table.

Next deploy remove the temp intermediate table.

It makes things easier if you make your scripts re-runnable so:

- In pre deploy check for the old table and if it exists copy to the intermediate table
  -In the post deploy use an outer join to only insert missing rows (or merge etc)

This means you don't have to be careful about only running this particular script once and you can take it out a few releases down the line if you want (remember to create a jira ticket or whatever)

The other thing that helps is that any foreign keys that are in modified tables are disabled before the pre-deploy and re-enabled after the post-deploy so you can setup any data you need without worrying about the intermediate state of the database :)

Hope it makes sense - i've written the steps up here which might make it clearer (https://the.agilesql.club/blog/Ed-Elliott/2015-12-30/Migrating-Data-In-SSDT-Without-Losing-It)

Ed